# Low-latency view-wide crosshair draw in Cocoa (over OpenGL view)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I need to draw a view-wide crosshair over openGL. Doing so in OpenGL using offscreen buffers didn't lead to great results (the latency is still significant) - crosshair lags behind the mouse pointer by a noticeable margin. And I don't know what other method to use or how to reduce the latency. Is this a limitation of the OpenGL pipeline?

I've tried doing it in Cocoa using layer-backed OpenGL view. But I don't find a way to avoid drawing in view's drawRect: function. And it still lags behind significantly. Any other faster method to draw it at Cocoa level?

These are basically two questions in one but either would help.